# Handle io.lettuce.core.RedisReadOnlyException when network is partitioned

Tags: redis, spring-data, sentinel

I have a situation where I use sentinel to get current redis master from sentinel. My setup is one redis master and three slaves and three sentinel nodes. This works fine in most situations but I have found that if I get a network split where the current master and the sentinel node that is configured first in the list of sentinel nodes are isolated from the other nodes, the other two sentinel nodes are doing a reelection to a new master, as intended.

My problem is that when the isolated previous master is accessing the common network again and is reconfigured to slave, my application is never notified that a new master is elected and continues to write to a slave since it still thinks it is writing to a master, ending up in getting "Error in execution; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisReadOnlyException: READONLY You can't write against a read only slave."

I do not know if this is a redis problem or framework problem. Should redis when it is reconfigured from master to save terminate the connection like it is done in normal circumstances when a new master is elected or should the framework handle exceptions and query for current master?

One more interesting aspect of this is if the sentinel node configured first in the sentinel node list continues to be isolated, the behavior continues even if the application accessing redis is restarted.

Is there any mechanism to handle this situation or is this a bug or enhancement to the framework?

Comment: It seems that we have the same situation during an upgrade of Kubernetes. Redis master node seems to be invalidated and a slave become master. But Lettuce do not see the updated master node .. We have to restart Redis node and everything works again ... did you found a workaround?

Comment: I had the same issue too, if someone has been able to manage that, I'll be glad to hear how.

Comment: @MattiasVendler did you figure out the issue. Was it in io.lettuce ?